# From html5 canvas to video

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, webrtc

What I am doing is some kind of a video conference tool. I am doing some research on video processing recently and it seems straight forward by using the video element in combination with canvases. But, I am using WebRTC for video streaming to all connected clients, for which I need a MediaStream. So I am looking for a way to retrieve a MediaStream from the canvas element. 
On my way, I found this project here called Whammy http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/ which creates a video file from a canvas, but as far as I understand, it is not made for live-streaming it.

One alternative approach would be to do the video processing on the remote client by sending him the stream and the information on how to process it. However this might work pretty well for few clients, but when it comes to multi-user conferences, I feel like it doesn't scale, since real-time video processing is still a calculation intense job. Every client would have to process all video streams from all connected clients.

For me it looks like a one-way-street. Getting video content into a canvas is pretty easy, the other way around is pretty hard. I thought, there might be a library for creating a MediaStream from a canvas element, but I found nothing. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Best,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted, there has been not much, but a little progress on this front.

The [MediaStream Recording](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) standard allows for recording streams (such as WebRTC) into video file formats, using the `MediaRecorder` API.

It should work with recent Firefox as well as Chrome (video only) enabling the latter via the experimental flags ( chrome://flags -> *Experimental Web Platform features*).

Also see [this resource for examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).